# How do i make a save feature or an android app?

Tags: android, arrays, listview, youtube

I have just finished my first app for android :D but I have one thing left to do. I want to know how to make a save feature to save progress on the app so the user does not have to start all over again when they turn the phone off or if the app gets closed completely. So how do i make a save feature that saves the progress of the app like updated values and new created objects etc? Can someone please help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Shared Preferences to save progress with a key-value pair**.Tutorial-[Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/)

```
//Create a file to store your preferences 
  String my_file_name = "contents"

//Create SharedPreferences Object
  SharedPreferences s_p 

//Link the file and object 
  s_p = getSharedPreferences(my_file_name,0);

//To enter values : use SharedPreferences.Editor
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = s_p.edit();

 //Add Values 
 editor.putString("key","value");
 editor.putInt("a",1); 

 //Commit Changes 
 editor.commit();

 //to get stored values 
 String vlaue = s_p.getString("key");
 int a = s_p.getInt("a");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into `persistent storage` [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) -- in Android this is often done in the form of `SharedPreferences` or a database. In your situation where all you need is local storage I'd suggest using either SharedPreferences or working with a local SQLite database.